# Is it possible to view one file in a new window in intellij-idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

What I actually want to do is to view different files in a some project on different screens.

If they are in different windows, I can easily drag one window to another screen.

It's fine if there are other ways can do this. I'm using windows7.

Comment: Simply use your editor of choice (notepad++ for me) to load up the files you want to simply refer to while using IntelliJ. Works best if you have a dual-monitor setup though. Or use maybe an app like winmerge if you want to see the exact differences between files?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can drag the editor tab to another screen and it will open in a separate window. See the [Detaching Editor Tabs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/detaching-editor-tabs.html) help section for details.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> does the same:

The shortcut can be changed here:

[image: new window]

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a new keyboard shortcut in your keymap.
The action is called `Open In New Editor Window`

[image: Keymap Open In New Editor Window]

Then when searching for a class using `Ctrl + n` (go to Class...) or `Ctrl + e` (recent files)
instead of opening the Class in the same window by pressing `Enter`
you can open it in a new window using your own keyboard shortcut (`Shift + Enter` in my case).

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click on tab.
2. Select `Move Tab to New Window` option.

[image]